# MongoDB running command in lithium

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb, lithium

I'm trying to run a full text search against some data that is stored in mongoDb using Lithium.

Here is how I am trying to do it in my controller:

```
$mongodb = Connections::get('default')->connection;
$results = Page::connection()->connection->command(array("text" => "Page", 'search' => "term" ));
```

I've also tried:

```
$results = Page::connection()->connection->command(array("text" => "Page", 'search' => "term" ));
```

However, both of these return:  Fatal error: Call to a member function command() on a non-object

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

I should add that a simple query on Page is working just fine. For instance:

```
$results = Page::find('all');
```

Does return an array with all of the documents in the pages collection like I would expect it to.

UPDATE 2:

I was running all of this from WAMP server. I tried today running it from a linux server, but still got the same exact error. I am really stumped by this and could use some help. Anyone have any ideas?

here is the Page model as it sits now:

```
<?php
namespace app\models;

use lithium\data\Connections; //added during debugging
use lithium\data\source\MongoDb; //added during debuging

class Page extends \lithium\data\Model {

}
?>
```

Here is my connection:

```
 Connections::add('default', array(
        'type' => 'MongoDb',
        'host' => '192.168.48.128',
        'database' => 'my_collection'
 ));
```

Comment: What's `Page`? Does it extend `lithium\data\Model`? I assume so. And where is your Lithium install from? Github? Composer? Do you have a version number?

Comment: Page is just a simple model. like so: 

`<?php
namespace app\models;

class Page extends \lithium\data\Model {
 
}
?>`

Not sure on version number, but I just downloaded it from gitHub 2 days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got help to figure it out... posting here for others to reference.

proper way of calling it is:

```
$conn = Model::connection();
$db = $conn->selectDB('db');
$result = $db->command(array(...
```

Works perfectly when done this way.

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing it this way:

```
$plugins = Plugins::connection()->connection->command([
    'text' => 'plugins',
     'search' => $this->request->query['q']
]);
return compact('plugins');
```

so I'd recommend checking your configuration - is your model returning other data normally? Is the connection configuration correct?

Comment: Yeah, my model is running returning simple finds just fine. Is this code being run from your controller, or from within your model? Are there any special imports/namespace/uses you have to use to get it to work?

Comment: Any chance you can let me know how your model was setup in your example?
Did you have to do anything special in your connections file?
Any 'use' declarations in your controller that are needed?